# When instancing an imported "class" from a package, how can i avoid using the package.class() declaration?

Tags: python, class

I'm kinda new to Python, so i'm still lost in the whole namespace thing.
I've created a package, with the init file in it and also a classname.py file, with the class, obviously.
For instance:
from parachute import container, emitter

I tried to instance the class Container directly, but it gave me an error, so i had to instance it as container.Container(). How can i avoid doing this? 
Basically, what i want to do is to import a class from a package and avoid typing the package name and/or the file name.
Thanks in advance, and please let me know if the question isn't clear enough.

UPDATE
The structure i have is:
- parachute
    -- **init**.py

```
-- container.py
    Serves as a controller, i'd say, instancing, calling and glueing all the other parts    together.

-- sparkles.py
    Has two classes: Sparkle and Sparkles. Sparkle is a single element, with only one    property so far, and Sparkles serves as a collection.  Sparkles() belongs to the Emitter, and Sparkle() belongs to Sparkles().

-- emitter.py 
    Emitter could be seen as the user entity. It has a name and an uid, it belongs to a Container and the Container belongs to it.
```

Now, from outside the package i'm calling Container and passing some arguments, and the Container instances and distributes the arguments as it needs.
I have the impression that this isn't the best way to do what i need to do, which is: Create a collection of sparkles, owned by the emitter.

Comment: Jorge - add four spaces at the start of each line for fixed-width formatting. I tried to clean it up, but it was hard to tell what the hierarchy was meant to be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the class in it's own file. Put `Container` and `Emitter` directly in `parachute.py`.

You can then do

```
from parachute import Container, Emitter
```

or

```
import parachute

container = parachute.Container()
```

This essentially boils down to "Python isn't Java so for best results, don't treat it like it is" ;)

Comment: In this case, parachute is a dir with an __init__ file in it (lol).How do i link everything together? Or should i make parachute a file, instead of a dir?

Comment: @Jorge, I would have to know more about the structure of the overall package. If you are just putting every class in it's own file though, then it should probably just be one file.

Comment: Here's what i've got so far: container.py (holds the sparkles), emitter.py (the 'owner' of a container), sparkles.py (contains Sparkle()and Sparkles(), which is a subclass of a list object, and serves as a collection of Sparkle() instances)

Comment: @Jorge, It all sounds related. I'd put it in one file. I'm not sure exactly what `Emmiter` is but it sounds like it should just be a module level function. You should probably update your question with the details that you just gave me though to get other opinions from people that don't read all of the comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
from module import Class
classInst = Class()
```

This will work if your class is in module.py